# Getting dimensions of text in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I was wondering how i get the dimensions of my text in SFML?

I tried to do it like this:

```
 sf::Text text("Hello SFML", font, 50);

// using text.getRect()
// i also tried getScale() & getSize()
// neither are correct

 text.setPosition( window.getSize().y/2 - text.getRect().y,50 );
```

Does any one know ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it seems like the function 
[`getLocalBounds`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Text.php#a8a766ea03a1b8899cd1542765771a4ae) could be of use to you.  The line would be:

```
float width = text.getLocalBounds().width;
```

I'm not sure if the `sf::Text` object would add any padding on the ends of the bounding rectangle.

Alternatively, you could make use of [`findCharacterPos`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Text.php#adf120ed4159e43daa782b17fea23ea82) with something like:

```
float width = text.findCharacterPos(numChars - 1).x - text.findCharacterPos(0).x;
```

where `numChars` is the number of characters in the string of your `text` object.  However, since `findCharacterPos` will return global coordinates, it's probably more convenient to use `getLocalBounds`, this way you don't have to worry about whether your `text` object has any transformations applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getGlobalBounds() to get the size/coordinates after a transformation (rotation, scale, move...).
Otherwise it's getLocalBounds().

Doc: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1/classsf_1_1Text.php